# What tool to use for Moblile Device Testing

Tags: mobile, cloud

We are building a responsive Ecommerce Website and would like to test it on several mobile devices on cloud. There are so many of them like AWSDEvice Farm, Sauce Labs, CrossBrowserWeb Testing etc.

We need the tool to perform some manual tests on real devices as well as run our Automated Selenium Scripts on real device.

Any thoughts or advice which ones are better from the ones mentioned above

Thanks
QA

Answer (score 0):

That's really hard to answer as it comes down a matter of opinon and all the specs of the project.

I don't know about the other but device farm has you upload the test package which can only be a appium java testng/junit or python pytest package.  Then in the public offering it will find a device and run the tests which may take longer than other options because it restarts the appium server between tests.

In the private offering for device farm, we can use direct device access to run any testing framework we want.  However, the up front cost for these is more than the public offering.

You are also limited in the execution time. Right now we can only run the tests up to 150 minutes.

Hope that helps

James